# window.open with ASP.net

Tags: asp.net

In my Asp.net application am trying to display files from the hyperlink, the hyperlink is inside of GridView and my script is

```
<a href="javascript:window.open('<%# Eval("Url") %>');">View Attachment</a>
```

the value for this Url is like , `localhost:1010/Attachments/test.jpg`

when I click this link, it displays the image in a new window, no problem.

But my application page displays only the `"[object]"`,nothing there except this.

am facing this problem only with IE, in chrome its showing perfectly...

how can I fix this, can anyone help me here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found in IE9 that by setting the return reference from `window.open` to a variable, the behavior you describe will be prevented from occuring.

```
<a href="javascript:var w1=window.open('<%# Eval("Url") %>');">View Attachment</a>
```

Comment: thanks DaveB, its opening in a new browser,is it possible to open in new window instead of new browser??

Comment: @Shanish - There are 2 ways that I know of to force a link to open in a new tab. 1) Hold down the Ctrl key when clicking the link. 2) the process outlined here: http://helpdeskgeek.com/how-to/force-ie-to-open-link-in-new-tab/. Both depend on the user. This behavior is not uniform amongst browsers.